# What is the purpose of tomcat-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, tomcat, plugins

I'm having some difficulty understanding the purpose of this plugin. Is it to modify the settings in Tomcat during the build?

I am deploying to tomcat using maven, without the plugin and it seems to work fine. Not sure if I am missing something

Cheers

Comment: What does not work? Which error messages did you get? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven Tomcat plugin basically just bootstraps an embedded Tomcat container for you. Saves you the trouble of configuring an external Tomcat instance for development purposes. It can also auto-start this Tomcat instance during the build and run integration tests on it, stopping it afterwards.
If you already have a functioning workflow that you're comfortable with, no need to introduce the plugin, but it's pretty easy to configure, can run multiple web apps, can run unassembled applications etc so it's convenient to have for local development.
An even more light-weight alternative would be the Jetty plugin which starts an embedded Jetty server instead.

Comment: Ahhhh its similiar to jetty. So if i had a seperate server building my Maven projects, if I had the tomcat plugin the code could run directly off the build server, and wouldnt need a separate app server?

Comment: Yes, that will happen if you trigger the plugin from the command on you build server, e.g. if your build server executes "mvn clean package tomcat7:run-war". But, this would be an unusual scenario. Normally, you'd keep deploying to your dedicated Tomcat from the build server (the build server is for building, not running the app, right?) and use the embedded one only for local development and probably for running integration tests during the build (e.g. if the build server triggers Maven's verify). Please accept the answer if it resolved your dilemma.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If there is an integrated Tomcat container does that mean the application server doesnt need to have Tomcat installed? Is that the benefit?

Comment: The embedded container is bootstrapped by the plugin (it does not end up in the WAR) and it is meant to be used only locally and during integration tests. In normal deployments (to a test server or production or whatever), you never invoke this plugin, so no embedded container exists. You do everything like you do it now: deploy the WAR to a dedicated Tomcat.

Comment: The benefit is that you have an easy automated integration testing platform and no need for a local Tomcat.

Comment: So without this plugin you cant perform your unit tests before deploying it to tomcat?

Comment: Integration tests, to be precise. To run them, you need an application server *somewhere*. Be it a standalone one or an embedded one. The plugin provides an embedded one that will automatically start and stop when needed and spares you the trouble of deployment. It also gives you a way to run the app locally even without assembling the WAR. This works wonders for reloading static files without rebuilds.

Comment: Ah I see, you don't need to assemble the war. Thank you. I think its probably not that useful for me.

Comment: Have witnessed several serious side-effects in using this plug-in since the class-loader and resource path resolution does not work the same via this method vs assembling WAR and deploying to Tomcat (emulating more precisely what occurs in real-world production run-time system). In addition, measured the run-time and see virtually no difference in running mvn install and then running a script to copy WAR file to Tomcat instance and starting that (resulting server 'started' time elapsed is virtually identical).

Answer (score 0):

Maven is actually a plugin execution framework where every task is actually done by plugins.

Maven Plugins are generally used to :

```
create jar file

create war file

compile code files

unit testing of code

create project documentation

create project reports
```

A plugin generally provides a set of goals and which can be executed using following syntax:

mvn [plugin-name]:[goal-name]

For example, a Java project can be compiled with the maven-compiler-plugin's compile-goal by running following command

mvn compiler:compile

[for more  information go to  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_plugins.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_plugins.htm)

so pulgins is used to execute goals.
suppose if you don't include plugin that is required in your execution environment then it will throw an error like

A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/BuildPluginManager;

so by adding appropriate plugin in pom.xml it will resolve the dependencies and execute the goal succesfully.

to remove above error just add the following plugins :

```
       <plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-amps-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${amps.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does the tomcat plugin allow you to do that makes it useful?

Answer (score -1):

Maven is a framework used to build JAVA applications, it provides the following

- Directory Structure
- Configuration Files
- Build Settings

It helps in easy and structured development, primarily used for REST API Calls.
Applications built on Maven Framework, would require the same to be deployed

Its better that you get the plugin installed, since on a long run you never know what dependency may go missing

-If this helps, Mark as Answer